# Various Moving Annual Totals in an SSAS Cube

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas, mdx

This is how I am creating my moving totals as columns in my cube:

**MATTY** (Moving Annual Total This Year)

```
SUM ( { [Time Period].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER.Lag(12) : [Time Period].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER }, [Measures].[MeasureColumnName])
```

**MATLY** (Moving Annual Total Last Year)

```
SUM ( { [Time Period].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER.Lag(24) : [Time Period].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER.Lag(12) }, [Measures].[MeasureColumnName])
```

How do I do the following?

**YTDTY** (Year To Date This Year)

**YTDLY** (Year To Date Last Year - up to same date as today)

Comment: You need to explain how you want the "to date" part to work. What do you want to use as your "anchor" date? You could use the current date/time based on the server clock. Or you could use the last data member that is non-empty. Or you could make it relative to whatever is the CurrentMember in the [Time Period] dimension.

Comment: the "To Date" means that when I look at YTD this year (and it is october), when I look at YTDLY, it shows me the total from Jan thru Oct last year as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a look at the [PeriodsToDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144925.aspx) and [YTD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146039.aspx) MDX functions on MSDN. Is there something more than those that you need?